# Como eliminar datos de tablas relacionadas con llaves Foraneas

Tags: mysql

Trato de eliminar datos relacionados con FK, de una base de datos, el tema es que me da error por las llaves FK (Restringidas), desconozco si se puede de todas formas eliminar datos sin desactivar o sin modificar las FK o por obligacion debo hacerlo.

Por ejemplo tengo estas tablas y debo eliminar la sucursal X junto a sus datos relacionados (Empleado, Proyecto)

Las tablas son estas

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS proyecto(
     numProyecto int NOT NULL,
     nombreProyecto CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (numProyecto)
    );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sucursales(
 numSucursales int NOT NULL,
 nombreSucursal VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 direccion VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 ciudad VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (numSucursales)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS empleados(
    numEmpleado int NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    sueldo bigint NOT NULL,
    fContratacion DATE NOT NULL,
    numSucursal int,
    jefe int NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (numEmpleado)
    CONSTRAINT fkjefe
    FOREIGN KEY (jefe) REFERENCES empleado(numEmpleado),
    CONSTRAINT fksucursal
    FOREIGN KEY (numSucursal) REFERENCES sucursales(numSucursal)
);

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ProyEmpleados(
     numProyecto int NOT NULL,
     numEmpleado int NOT NULL,
     fechaInicio DATE NOT NULL,
     fechaTermino DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fkEmpleadoPro
    FOREIGN KEY (numEmpleado) REFERENCES empleados(numEmpleado),
    CONSTRAINT fkProyectoEmple
    FOREIGN KEY (numProyecto) REFERENCES Proyecto(numProyecto)
    );
```

He tratado de efectuar la eliminacion una en una pero siempre topo con las FK, se que podria desactivar las FK y borrar pero no se si tengo otra alternativa.

Comment: Las FK están para proteger los datos de incumplir _reglas de negocio_. "No tiene sentido que haya un empleado sin sucursal", por ejemplo. Si estás chocando con una FK es porque quieres usar la opción nuclear y tal vez no sea buena idea. Si tu aplicación ofrece borrar una sucursal, deberías entonces ofrecer la opción de reasignar empleados a otra para que no queden _desempleados_ :)

Comment: @Alfabravo claro fue lo que pense, pero mas que aplicacion lo que tengo es una base de datos en MySQL y me piden generar un Query que permita realizar eso eliminar la sucursal junto a los empleado y Proyectos asociados, por lo tanto mi unica solucion por asi decirlo es desactivando las FK o bien generar nuevas FK en Cascada, al final se debe si o si eliminar al ampleado y proyectos asociados. :(

por eso queria ver otra alternativa que permita borrar eso sin desactivar las FK o crearlas nuevamente.

Comment: Podrías pensar en usar un procedimiento almacenado (stored procedure) donde crees un bloque de transacción y ahí puedes hacer varias consultas, varios update y delete que, si alguno falla, se dé un rollback... con eso haces una secuencia como reasignar empleados, borrar sucursal, etc. Casi siempre se puede sin bomba atómica... a veces toca pero siempre es sano intentar a las buenas primero